\textbf value coordinate in bar graph
I'm trying to write the value "725" in bold using \textbf in LaTeX, but the system is giving me an error. How can I fix it?
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[lmargin=1.3in, rmargin=1in, tmargin=1in, bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            symbolic x coords={40, 28, 22, 16, 7, 5, 3, 2},
            xtick=data,
            ylabel={Cost (in million \$)},
            xlabel={Nanometers},
            bar width=15pt,
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            nodes near coords,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=900,
            grid=major,
            grid style={dashed},
            width=0.75\textwidth,
            height=0.5\textwidth,
            tick label style={font=\large},
            label style={font=\large},
            every node near coord/.append style={font=\large, color=black}, % Imposta il colore azzurrino per i numeri
        ]
        \addplot+[
            ybar,
            fill=black,
            draw=cyan, % Imposta il bordo delle barre in azzurrino
            nodes near coords,
            point meta=y,
        ] coordinates {
            (40, 36)
            (28, 48)
            (22, 63)
            (16, 90)
            (7, 249)
            (5, 449)
            (3, 581)
            (2, 725)
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Average chip design cost by chip size (in million \$).}
\end{figure}



Apart from the missing \begin{document}---\end{document}, the code compiles without errors.

the code you post should be related to your question. It has no \begin{document} so produces no output, and has no \textbf when you are asking why \textbf produces an error.

The solution for printing a number in bold is not easy, it seems (I hope somebody can help here with a simpler solution). My approach would be to use visualization depends on  and a couple of tricks from this answer.
The idea is to use a table instead of coordinates, and to add an additional column. In this case I called it b and when the value is 1, the number on the bar is typeset bold. It should be possible to use a point meta from coordinates also, as shown here, but I do not know how to access the explicit value then...
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=1.3in, rmargin=1in, tmargin=1in, bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            symbolic x coords={40, 28, 22, 16, 7, 5, 3, 2},
            xtick=data,
            ylabel={Cost (in million \$)},
            xlabel={Nanometers},
            bar width=15pt,
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            nodes near coords,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=900,
            grid=major,
            grid style={dashed},
            width=0.75\textwidth,
            height=0.5\textwidth,
            tick label style={font=\large},
            label style={font=\large},
            every node near coord/.append style={font=\large, color=black},
        ]
        \addplot+[
            ybar,
            fill=black,
            draw=cyan, % Imposta il bordo delle barre in azzurrino
            nodes near coords={
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\myintb{\myb}%
                \ifnum \myintb = 1 %
                    {\boldmath{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\myy}}}%
                \else
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\myy}%
                \fi
            },
            % points meta = explicit symbolic,
            visualization depends on={\thisrow{y} \as \myy},
            visualization depends on={\thisrow{b} \as \myb},
        ] table {
            x  y  b
            40 36 0
            28 48 0
            22 63 0
            16 90 0
            7 249 1
            5 449 0
            3 581 0
            2 725 1
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


